# Autocomplete not showing suggestion list when triggered second time

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have autocomplete with two sources. When an item is selected after search from first source, if certain conditions are met, the second search is forced. This brings back results - I can see them writing into console but the list of suggestions will not show up unless "keypress" is made. I tried to automate this with forcing the .ui-list to show and with forcing "keypress" events but to no avail... has anybody got any experience and advice on this? Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var stopSearch = false;
    var sel = "";
    var finished = false;

    $('#txtLiveDept').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            console.log("stopSearch" + stopSearch);
            if (stopSearch == false) {
                console.log("first ajax");
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/en-gb/LiveDepartures/CombinedAjax',
                    data: "{ inputTerm: '" + request.term + "'}",
                    //dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    autoFocus: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data.Locations);
                        console.log(data.ServiceResponses);
                        if (data)
                        var resp1 = data.Locations;
                        var resp2 = data.ServiceResponses;
                        var dataF = resp2.concat(resp1);
                        console.log(dataF);
                        response($.map(dataF, function (item) {
                            console.log("item" + item.FullText);
                            var label = "";
                            if (item.FullText == undefined) {
                                label = item.ServiceNumber + ", " + item.Description;
                            }
                            else {
                                label = item.FullText;
                            }
                            return {
                                Label: label,
                                FullText: item.FullText,
                                Category: item.Category,
                                Latitude: item.Latitude,
                                Longitude: item.Longitude,
                                value: label,
                                StopLabel: item.StopLabel,
                                ServiceId: item.ServiceId
                            }
                        }));

                        failure: function err(response) {
                            console.log("error: " + response.d);
                        }
                    },
                });
            }
            else if (stopSearch == true) {
                console.log("second ajax");
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/en-gb/LiveDepartures/GetStops',
                    data: "{ serviceId: '" + sel + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    autoFocus: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                console.log("item" + item.Name + item.StopLabel);
                                $("#txtLiveDept").val("");
                                $(".ui-menu").show();
                                console.log("just before");
                                return {
                                    label: item.Name + ", " + item.StopLabel,
                                    FullText: item.FullText,
                                    Category: item.Category,
                                    Latitude: item.Latitude,
                                    Longitude: item.Longitude,
                                    value: item.Name + ", " + item.StopLabel,
                                    StopLabel: item.StopLabel,
                                    ServiceId: item.ServiceId
                                };
                            }));
                        }
                    },
                });
            }
        },
        select: function (e, selected) {
            console.log("selected:" + selected.item.ServiceId);
            if (selected.item.ServiceId != undefined) {
                console.log("in third");
                sel = selected.item.ServiceId;
                var item = selected.item.ServiceId;
                console.log("third item" + item);
                stopSearch = true;
                console.log("finished" + finished);
                if (finished == false) {
                    $("#txtLiveDept").autocomplete("search", item);
                }
                else {
                    alert("hey");
                }
            }               
        },
        minLength: 0
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your `select` callback, I would advise adding a `return false;` to the end of it.

Comment: I also see some syntax issues within your first AJAX call. You never seem to close your `success` callback so the `failure` callback never gets properly defined.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that. Much appreciated. I repaired both. Still not getting the list to show without action though.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the following code.

```
$(function() {
  var stopSearch = false;
  var sel = "";
  var finished = false;

  function getCombined(q) {
    var results;
    $.ajax({
      url: '/en-gb/LiveDepartures/CombinedAjax',
      data: {
        inputTerm: q
      },
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.Locations);
        console.log(data.ServiceResponses);
        if (data.length) {
          var dataF = data.Locations.concat(data.ServiceResponses);
          console.log(dataF);
          results = $.map(dataF, function(item) {
            console.log("item" + item.FullText);
            var label = "";
            if (item.FullText == undefined) {
              label = item.ServiceNumber + ", " + item.Description;
            } else {
              label = item.FullText;
            }
            return {
              Label: label,
              FullText: item.FullText,
              Category: item.Category,
              Latitude: item.Latitude,
              Longitude: item.Longitude,
              value: label,
              StopLabel: item.StopLabel,
              ServiceId: item.ServiceId
            }
          });
        }
      },
      failure: function err(response) {
        console.log("error: " + response.d);
      }
    });
    return results;
  }

  function getStops(q) {
    var results;
    $.ajax({
      url: '/en-gb/LiveDepartures/GetStops',
      data: {
        serviceId: q
      },
      dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.length) {
          results = $.map(data, function(item) {
            console.log("item" + item.Name + item.StopLabel);
            $("#txtLiveDept").val("");
            $(".ui-menu").show();
            console.log("just before");
            return {
              label: item.Name + ", " + item.StopLabel,
              FullText: item.FullText,
              Category: item.Category,
              Latitude: item.Latitude,
              Longitude: item.Longitude,
              value: item.Name + ", " + item.StopLabel,
              StopLabel: item.StopLabel,
              ServiceId: item.ServiceId
            };
          });
        }
      }
    });
    return results;
  }

  $('#txtLiveDept').autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    source: function(request, response) {
      console.log("stopSearch", stopSearch);
      if (stopSearch) {
        console.log("second ajax");
        response(getStops(sel));
      } else {
        console.log("first ajax");
        response(getCombined(request.term));
      }
    },
    select: function(e, selected) {
      console.log("selected:" + selected.item.ServiceId);
      if (selected.item.ServiceId != undefined) {
        console.log("in third");
        sel = selected.item.ServiceId;
        var item = selected.item.ServiceId;
        console.log("third item" + item);
        stopSearch = true;
        console.log("finished" + finished);
        if (finished == false) {
          $("#txtLiveDept").autocomplete("search", item);
        } else {
          alert("hey");
        }
      }
      return false;
    },
    minLength: 0
  });
  $('#txtLiveDept').focus(function(){
    $(this).autocomplete("search");
  });
});
```